# How to reuse an angular component multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I'm learning the basics of angular, but i still can't figure out how to reuse the same component multiple times in the same document.

This is the relevant code:

test.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './test.component';

@NgModule({
imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

test.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./test-common.css"],
  })

  export class AppComponent  { 

  name = 'Angular'; 

  changeName() {
    this.name = "duck";
  }
}
```

test.component.html

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<button (click)="changeName()">Click me!</button>
```

and this is the main index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular QuickStart</title>
<base href="/">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<example>Loading ...</example>
<example>Loading ...</example>
<example>Loading ...</example>
<example>Loading ...</example>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is: i wanted angular to add the component to every "example" tag in index.html. But i see it works only for the first tag while the others are ignored. Can you help me to understand this behaviour?

thanks in advance

Comment: Just follow the 'Tour of Heroes' https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Comment: i've already followed that tutorial, it uses the ngFor to load multiple copies of the same component. But i'd like to see an example where angular loads the component every time there is an "example" tag

Comment: You can do it within your app.component

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that in your application the `example` is the root component. Angular process only one DOM element for the root component at the top level. Here is how you can modify your `example` template to see it rendered multiple times:

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<button (click)="changeName()">Click me!</button>

<!-- rendered multiple times -->
<b-comp></b-comp>
<b-comp></b-comp>
```

And add `BComponent` into the application:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'b-comp',
  template: `<span>b-comp</span>`
})

export class BComponent {
}
```

And add it to the `declarations` in `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
   imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
   declarations: [ AppComponentl, BComponent ],
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: mmm, i think i understood, but i can't put together a working example

Comment: what's the error you get? you also need to referent the `BComponent` in `AppModule`, I added this information to the answer

Comment: No errors shown but the example doesn't work at all. I have very little experience with angular, i've added a new b.component.ts and b.module.ts as instructed. I've modified test.component.html as you suggested. Do i have to change anything in index.html? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain myself correctly, i need the "<h1> + <button>" to be repeated 4 times, once for every "example" tag.

Comment: @rekotc, well, you'll have `<span>b-comp</span>` repeated 2 times in my example because it's the template of `BComponent`. Just put whatever html you need into `BComponent`