# Using a component more than once in a single parent component

Tags: angular, components

I am working on an items App. Now, A can transfer items to B. My interface is simple: list of members to chose from as source on left and to whom to give on the right. Since the source of the information, appearance and search functionality is the same, I thought of creating one component that I can use here (and in another component that requires similar interface). Here is a realistic but simplified version:

In parent.ts, html I have:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Source</label>
    <app-browser></app-browser>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Destination</label>
    <app-browser></app-browser>
</div>
```

The AppBrowser.componenet.ts:

```
selected_g:number=0; //nothing selected yet.

eventSelect(){

    var element=document.ElementByID('data') as HTMLSelectElement;

    let value:number=+element.value;

    if(value==0){
        alert('Make a selection');
        return false;
    }

    this.selected_g=value;
}
```

the template:

```
<select id="data">
    <option value="0">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">G1</option>
    <option value="2">G2</option>
</select>
<button (click)="eventSelect()">Confirm</button>
```

Now the problem is: if I select a valid option in the first (source i.e. the instance I inserted first), the second instance (destination) has no effect. That is, I can select value 0 and click Confirm and it wouldn't complain. It would complain if the first instance has selected 0 only. I was under the impression components are like classes: if I insert the components multiple times, each one would work in its own right/space. But it appears only the first instance manages the whole thing. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071244/how-to-reuse-an-angular-component-multiple-times

Comment: Thanks @match I did check it out before I posted, felt it is different. Apology if I spammed.

Comment: Well I wasn't aware of this issue, so having the post has helped me learn something. Here's a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pkPYfm) I just created which shows what I believe it your required behaviour working with a 'sub' component.

Comment: If you agree this is a duplicate,  please hit 'close' it and mark it as a duplicate to keep things tidy!

Comment: Just updated your plunkr; but still the same error. Can you play with it and see what I mean: eventSelect() should alert false if you select "Select One". But here, the whole thing is determined by the first instance.

Comment: Just updated your plunkr; but still the same error. Can you play with it and see what I mean: eventSelect() should alert false if you select "Invalid Option". But here, the whole thing is determined by the first instance. But neverthless, I have solved thru some other means. Thanks.

Comment: Some other points to make - am turning this into an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here. The first is the same issue raised at [How to reuse an angular component multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071244/how-to-reuse-an-angular-component-multiple-times) - angular will process only one DOM element for the root component - so you can't have more than one `<app-browser>` tag. However it works if you move the select code into a sub-component - see this [plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/pkPYfm)

The 2nd issue is that you are using `id="data"` in `select` in the template. Since you are then trying to fetch it using `document.getElementById('data')` it will always return the first one it finds. This means that if the first field is unselected, then even if you change the 2nd one the alert will always fire since the first `id` is the first one returned from the document.

To fix this you need a unique id for each instance of the component. You could do this manually, e.g. `<my-sub [id]="xxx">` or posisbly generate it dynamically.

In angular 1.x this could be done with `$id` - I'm not sure what the correct way to do this in 2+ is - but you could do worse than use e.g. `Math.random()` Here's a modification of the original example using `Math.random()`: [plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mW2LHA)

Finally, it might only be applicable to this instance, but the effect of repeating the component could be done in other ways - for example using `ngFor` in the `root` or `sub` component, providing arguments (including an `id`) if useful.

Comment: Hey @match thanks. That's how i solved it as well, thanks so much.