# How can I associate different datasets with multiple components in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have created a custom dropdown component in Angular 7 that takes an array as input. Currently, it is used to display a list of countries. This works perfect if this dropdown component only appears once in the parent component. But now I need to use the dropdown component twice in the same parent component - once to display the list of countries, and the other to display states. Even if I am passing in different data sets, it is only displaying the first one that appears in the parent component. My question is, how would I associate each dropdown with the specific data set?

Dropdown component:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <ul class="list">
        <li *ngFor="let item of listToFilter; let i = index;" class="item" id="{{'item-'+i}}">  
        {{item.value}} - {{item.description}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Parent component:

```
<app-custom-dropdown [listToFilter]="countries" (itemSelected)="getSelectedCountry($event)"></app-custom-dropdown>
```

Comment: Could you please try with assigning different Id's for both, Also this link might helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370756/using-a-component-more-than-once-in-a-single-parent-component

Comment: It should work. Thats the use of re-useable components.  For seocnd drop down use [listToFilter]="states" where states is different variable.

Comment: @EnigmaState I did try with different ID's, still was not working for me. I will take a look at the link. vipulpatel I did associate the new dataset with the [listToFilter] but it didn't work. Hence my question